# When does $P(x,y)$ is a function of $x+2y$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Suppose $P$ is a polynomial of two real variables $x$ and $y.$

> How can I prove that $P(x,y)$ is a function of $x+2y$ if and only if $P_y=2P_x$ ?

Here $P_x=\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial x}.$

Is there any purely algebraic way to determine this?
(than using derivatives)

Comment: what do you mean by function of x+2y?

Comment: @Fundamental: For example $$P(x,y)=(x+2y)^3+2(x+2y)^2-3(x+2y)+4.$$

Comment: @Fundamental: In other words $$P(x,y)=P(x+2y,0)$$

Comment: @Nilan By the way, the requirement that $P(x,y)$ is a polynomial does not seem to be necessary, if my answer is correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the forward implication use chain rule;

$$ P(x,y) = P(x+2y,0) \Rightarrow P_y = \nabla P \cdot \left\langle \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x+2y), \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(0) \right\rangle = 2P_x$$

Answer (score 1):

(The forward implication is rephrased from a previous answer)

If $P(x,y)=f(x+2y)$, then
$$P_x=f'(x+2y) \frac{\partial (x+2y)}{\partial x}=f'(x+2y)$$
and
$$P_y=f'(x+2y) \frac{\partial (x+2y)}{\partial y}=2 f'(x+2y)=2 P_x$$

Now, assume $P_y=2P_x$. The polynomial $P$ can be written as a function of $x+2y$ if and only if substituting $x+2y$ by 0 yields a constant, i.e. iif $g(x)=P(x,-\frac{x}{2})$ is constant. But:
$$ g'(x) =P_x(x,-\frac{x}{2}) \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} + P_y(x,-\frac{x}{2}) \frac{\partial (-\frac{x}{2})}{\partial x} = P_x(x,-\frac{x}{2})  + 2 P_x(x,-\frac{x}{2}) (-\frac{1}{2}) =0$$
so $g(x)$ is constant, which completes the proof.

NOTE: What do you mean "algebraic way"? If your condition is differential, you will have to use derivatives...